# shell script to delete all files except the last updated file in different folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

My application logs will be created in below folders in linux system.

```
Folder 1: 100001_1001
folder 2 : 200001_1002
folder 3 :300061_1003
folder 4: 300001_1004
folder 5 :400011_1008
```

want to delete all files except the latest file in above folders and want to add this to cron job.

i tried below one not working need help

```
30 1 * * * ls -lt /abc/cde/etc/100* | awk '{if(NR!=1) print $9}' | xargs -i rm -rf {} \;
30 1 * * * ls -lt /abc/cde/etc/200* | awk '{if(NR!=1) print $9}' | xargs -i rm -rf {} \;
30 1 * * * ls -lt /abc/cde/etc/300* | awk '{if(NR!=1) print $9}' | xargs -i rm -rf {} \;
30 1 * * * ls -lt /abc/cde/etc/400* | awk '{if(NR!=1) print $9}' | xargs -i rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Is `200001_1002` a filename?

Comment: What do those commands do when you don't run them from cron? Do the individual parts (things between pipes) do what you think they do?

Comment: 200001_1002 is dir name , all are dir's which has many zip files inside the dir . want to delete all .zip's except the latest one.

Comment: i am doing individual parts listing all logs(zips) in dir which start with 100, 200 etc and trying to remove the all zip except the latest one .once the job is done want to add to cron tab

Comment: Well ... the problem with your own approach is with the last step; you're feeding rm only filenames; rm however doesn't know anything about the paths. Had you tried to answer my second question you would have noticed.  That said: parsing ls output is a recipe for disaster in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pipeline consisting all gnu utilities (so that we can also handle file paths with special characters, whitespaces and glob characters)

```
find /parent/log/dir -type f -name '*.zip' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
sort -zk1,1rn |
cut -zf2 |
tail -z -n +2 |
xargs -0 rm -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a slightly modified approach to your own:

```
find /abc/cde/etc/100* -printf "%A+\t%p\n" | sort -k1,1r| awk 'NR!=1{print $2}' | xargs -i rm "{}"
```

The find version doesn't suffer the lack of paths, so this MIGHT work (I don't know anything about the directory structure, and whether 100* points at a directory, a file or a group of files ...

Comment: this 100* is dir list which will start with 100 and having lot of files inside

Comment: And does my approach work for you?  W/o mimicking your directory structure and running it against /usr/share/man/pl/man* with an "echo rm" instead of "rm" it seems to do "the right thing" on my system ... @user1206219

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find`, instead. It has a `-delete` action that deletes he files it found that match you specification. **Warning**: it is very easy to go wrong with `-delete`. Test your command first. Example, to find all files named `*.zip` under `a/b/c` (and only files):

```
find a/b/c -depth -name '*.zip' -type f -print
```

This is the test, it will print all files that the final command will delete (do not forget the `-depth`, it is important). And once you are sure, the command that does the deletion is:

```
find a/b/c -depth -name '*.zip' -type f -delete
```

`find` also has options to select files by last modification date, by size... You could, for instance, find all files that were modified at least 24 hours ago:

```
find a/b/c -depth -type f -mtime +0 -print
```

and, after careful check, delete them:

```
find a/b/c -depth -type f -mtime +0 -delete
```